# Do you need to have insurance on an unused car?

Tags: united-states, insurance, car, car-insurance, colorado

I'm buying a car and garaging it until I can fix it. Do I need to have insurance on it to be able to register it (so I won't get fined for not registering it) or can I just register it like that since I won't be driving it for a few months?

Comment: Legal questions require a country, and may require a state.

Comment: USA colorado elpaso county

Comment: If you're not driving it why do you need to register it until you do start driving it? Regarding insurance, you should insure it if you think it could be stolen before you are able to fix it and drive it.

Comment: Because I read something about being able to be fined if you don't register it 30 days after purchasing it.  It'll be in my garage so it's safe but  Idk if you need insurance  to  register  it

Comment: Unless the 30 days thing is a lie

Comment: New cars are not registered until someone buys them, I am sure there are many sitting in car yards for more than 30 days.

Comment: But it said something after a person buying it

Comment: is there a car tax in your state/county. In Virginia you have to register it with the local government within 60 days or there are fines/liens.

Comment: Yes, you should register. I left a car (registered but uninsured) at home in Arizona while living for a few years in Germany. I would check w your DMV to see if they have an option for inactive vehicle registration.

Comment: So I don't need insurance  for it?

Comment: you could always call the Colorado DMV.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mandatory insurance is [required for registration](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/dmv/registration-requirements). But the requirements are for liability insurance. You may submit [affidavit of non-use](https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/DR2303_2.pdf) and will not be required to have insurance (at least that's how I understand it).

Registration is required within 60 days, not 30 (same link as above).

Insurance for the damage or loss to your car - up to you. If you don't care if it gets stolen or burns with your house or gets damaged when a rodent eats through the tires while you're not watching - then don't get insurance. Keep in mind, that if for some reason the breaks fail, the garage door gives in, and the car rolls out on to the street and causes damage/casualties - it will be on you.

Comment: But is insurance mandatory when registering it and it won't roll rodents get killed by my cat plus it needs new tires and if my house burns down it'd be covered because of homeowners insurance. If not then I'm down 400 dollars

Comment: @user36537 I put a link to the DMV page, it doesn't explicitly say that if you sign affidavit of non-use then the insurance is not required, but that is what I understand from how they phrased it.

Comment: Does affidavit of non use supplement  the registration  while the vehicle  is being repaired or  do you have to do both

Comment: @user36537 your question is a bit of a tautology... Yes, it supplements. Which means - yes, you need to do both.

Comment: I meant like can you do one  or the other haha

Comment: But I think you just answered that  haha